# How to set solid background color in grub

Tags: grub2

[image]

This is how my grub looks like when I start the system up now

I added this line to my `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND=''
```

to unset the default background, but I want to set this blue color to black. How do I do it?

I do not want to set a black background image in order to make it appear black. I want to set the background color to solid black.

`uname -a` gives me the following output

```
Linux earth 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2kali1 (2017-06-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Grub2#Configure_console_menu_colors) states that the grub menu colors can be changed by creating a file `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` with for example the following content

```
set color_normal=light-gray/black
```

This worked for me on Debian Stretch and may work on other Debian based distributions.

Comment: That actually worked for me, I'm running Pop!_OS 21.04. I used the values `set menu_color_normal=white/black` and `set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `/etc/default/grub` is the place to configure this.
Now that `GRUB_BACKGROUND` is unset, you are most of the way.
There are two other options that should be of interest to you.

- `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="foreground/background"`: sets the colours of a line that is not currently selected
- `GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="foreground/background"`: sets the colours of the currently selected line

If you ensure that background is set to black in both of these options ypou should have the effect that you are after.
This works on a system with grub 2.02
If this doesn't work, try setting `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console`.

Comment: Just tried, it did not work. :( I tried `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="foreground/background"` and `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="foreground"` and `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="background"` and `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="BLACK"` and `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="" and same options with `GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` and also I mentioned `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console` but the color did not change from blue to black

Comment: The foreground and background in the answer are just placeholder values. try `GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-blue/black"` and `GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-cyan/black"`.

Comment: Tried and saw no change again, it's still the same. Also it's worth mentioning that after changing `/etc/default/grub`, I'm doing `update-grub` and then `init 6`

Comment: I think that there is something specific to your distribution that is overwriting your changes. Based on the fact that you're using the `update-grub` wrapper script rather than `grub-mkconfig` directly, I'm guessing you're using something Debian based. Check in `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, seems like you're falling back to the "traditional Debian blue theme".